# How to manage priority of queued jobs using laravel horizon?

Tags: php, laravel, priority-queue, laravel-queue

This is a theoretical question, please do not report as spam.

I am working on a web application of P2P cryptocurrency exchange. There is a feature to swap one cryptocurrency into another one. Lets say, I have BTC and I need to convert it in ETH equivalent amount.

As soon as a user visits swap page, My code fetches exchange rates from 7 third party exchanges like below image.

[image: Crypto swapping page]

What here I am doing in background is I am hitting these 7 exchanges using guzzle in queued jobs and as soon as any I get data from any exchange it is broadcasted to event listeners and channels.

It works perfectly when I and my team of 5-6 people test this functionality. I can see the jobs are processed in laravel horizon dashboard very quick.

Next I hosted my application on live server with domain name, I tried blazemeter, a perfomance testing tool. Where I would give API url of this page (I am using vuejs) and allocate 50 users to make request to this api. Here what I learned that around 40k jobs are queued in horizon dashboard and its performance degraded drastically and time to finish those jobs were displayed as 4 hours. Which is not possible for a normal user to wait for getting response.

So my question is what is the best approach to mitigate this issue, when in production. How to prioritize the queued jobs.

I am using redis and queue driver.

Comment: Show the horizon config?

Answer (score -3):

Just don't make job for each user every time.
Make a cron job to fetch data regularly for all currencies and store them somewhere. You can divide jobs for each service in different worker if they are too many.
Then when user hit "Buy" button you can do another check of the price if it has changed.

Comment: The question is "How to manage priority", so while your answer could be a relevant addendum, it absolutely doesn't answer the initial issue.